# Elasticsearch aggregation on distinct keys

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I want to aggregate my documents over the different keys in the field "categories".
Here are two documents:

```
      "date": 1470271301,
      "categories": {
        "1": [blabla],
        "2": [blala]
      }


      "date": 144343545,
      "categories": {
        "1": [blabla],
        "2": [coco]
        "3": [rat, saouth]
      }
```

Mapping for categories:

```
"categories" : {
    "properties" : {
        "1" : {
            "type" : "long"
```

And i want get something like this:

```
 "buckets" : [ {
    "key" : "1",
    "doc_count" : 2
  }, {
    "key" : "2",
    "doc_count" : 2
    {
    "key" : "3",
    "doc_count" : 1
  }
```

Is there a good way to do this whithout changing the mapping of my documents?

Comment: Would be helpful if you post the current mapping for categories

Comment: @keety mapping posted

Answer (score 3):

One could use the meta-field  [_field_names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-field-names-field.html) for this purpose.

Running aggregate on this as shown in the example below would  give you the document count.

Example :

```
put test/test/1 
{
    "date": 1470271301,
      "categories": {
        "1": ["blabla"],
        "2": ["blala"]
      }
}
put test/test/2 
{
   "date": 144343545,
      "categories": {
        "1": ["blabla"],
        "2": ["coco"],
        "3": ["rat", "saouth"]
      }
}

POST test/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "field_documents": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "_field_names",
            "include" : "categories.*",
            "size": 0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Result :

```
  "aggregations": {
      "field_documents": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "categories",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "categories.1",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "categories.2",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "categories.3",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```