# Aggregating over _field_names in elasticsearch 5

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'm trying to aggregate over field names in ES 5 as described in [Elasticsearch aggregation on distinct keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228585/elasticsearch-aggregation-on-distinct-keys) But the solution described there is not working anymore.

My goal is to get the keys across all the documents. Mapping is the default one.

Data:

```
PUT products/product/1
{
    "param": {
        "field1": "data",
        "field2": "data2"
    }   
}
```

Query:

```
GET _search
{
    "aggs": {
        "params": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "_field_names",
                "include" : "param.*",   
                "size": 0
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I get following error: `Fielddata is not supported on field [_field_names] of type [_field_names]`

Comment: you can try replace '_field_names' to '_field_names.keyword'.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around it seems the only way in ES > 5.X to get the unique field names is through the mappings endpoint, and since cannot aggregate on the `_field_names` you may need to slightly change your data format since the mapping endpoint will return every field regardless of nesting.

My personal problem was getting unique keys for various child/parent documents.

I found if you are prefixing your field names in the format `prefix.field` when hitting the mapping endpoint it will automatically nest the information for you.

```
PUT products/product/1
{
    "param.field1": "data",
    "param.field2": "data2",
    "other.field3": "data3"
}   

GET products/product/_mapping
{
    "products": {
        "mappings": {
            "product": {
                "properties": {
                    "other": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field3": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "param": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field1": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "field2": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can grab the unique fields based on the prefix.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because [setting `size: 0` is not allowed anymore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_50_aggregations_changes.html#_literal_size_0_literal_on_terms_significant_terms_and_geohash_grid_aggregations) in ES 5. You have to set a specific size now.

```
POST _search
{
    "aggs": {
        "params": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "_field_names",
                "include" : "param.*",   
                "size": 100                <--- change this
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. The error is: `Fielddata is not supported on field [_field_names] of type [_field_names]`

Comment: Hmm, that's a different issue. Can you try to remove the `include` parameter altogether?

Comment: I have tried removing include on my own machine, to no avail.