# How to get all field names in elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I just start using elasticsearch 5.2 .

I am trying to get all keys in the index 
 if I have the following mapping:

```
"properties": {
         "name": { "type": "text" },
         "article": {
          "properties": {
           "id": { "type": "text" },
           "title":  { "type": "text"},
           "abstract": { "type": "text"},
            "author": {
             "properties": {
              "id": { "type": "text" },
              "name": { "type": "text" }
}}}} } }
```

**is it possible to get all fields full name ?**
 like this:

```
 name,
 article.id ,
 article.title ,
 article.abstract ,
 article.author.id,
 article.author.name
```

how can I get that ?

Comment: are you trying to get aggregations or documents by those fields ?

Comment: I am trying to get the fields names list . maybe the aggregation trial is confusing . I will remove it. thanks

Comment: then you can use source filtering 
-- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html

Comment: I don't understand how that will yield only field names of the index

Comment: ES returns all fields by default, if you want to exclude fields from source you can use source filtering. Maybe i couldnt understand your question ?

Comment: thanks @eyildiz but filtering will not do it . I simply want to list all fields . so for ```article": {
          "properties": {
           "id": { "type": "text" },
           "title":  { "type": "text"}}}``` 
I want 
article.id,
article.title

Comment: i see now, you want to get field names, not fields by name like getting column names on sql. this would be helpful maybe -- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-field-mapping.html

Answer (score 3):

You may use [_field_names](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/mapping-field-names-field.html) field.

> The _field_names field indexes the names of every field in a document
>   that contains any value other than null.

```
GET _search
{
  "size"0,
  "aggs": {
    "Field names": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_field_names", 
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update : from ES 5 onwards

> the _field_names field has been locked down and is only indexed, it
>   doesn't support fielddata (memory intensive) or doc values,

Ref : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22576

As an alternative, you may [getMapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html)

> The get mapping API can be used to get more than one index or type
>   mapping with a single call. General usage of the API follows the
>   following syntax: host:port/{index}/_mapping/{type}

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/index/_mapping?pretty'
```

You may then process the response to extract all the field names in the index

Comment: tried that but I am getting :
`"root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Fielddata is not supported on field [_field_names] of type [_field_names]"
      }
    ],`

Comment: IIUC I cannot use the `_field_names` in aggregations as suggested

Comment: Yes, you may only query for the existence of a field but can't aggregate on the same.

Comment: you can also use get _mapping api but that would require some coding on your part

Comment: The get mappings approach will not work if you are using the join functionality.  If you want to get the fields from a strictly child document this is not possible, since you cannot match your join field value.

Comment: I found a solution, which I think may be suggested but not obvious in redlus's answer.  See my answer in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48724411/3453043

Answer (score 3):

The mapping API also allows querying the field names directly.
Here is a python 3 code snippet which should do the work:

```
import json
import requests

# get mapping fields for a specific index:
index = "INDEX_NAME"
elastic_url = "http://ES_HOSTNAME:9200"
doc_type = "DOC_TYPE"
mapping_fields_request = "_mapping/field/*?ignore_unavailable=false&allow_no_indices=false&include_defaults=true"
mapping_fields_url = "/".join([elastic_url, index, doc_type, mapping_fields_request])
response = requests.get(mapping_fields_url)

# parse the data:
data = response.content.decode()
parsed_data = json.loads(data)
keys = sorted(parsed_data[index]["mappings"][doc_type].keys())
print("index= {} has a total of {} keys".format(index, len(keys)))

# print the keys of the fields:
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    if i % 43 == 0:
        input()
    print("{:4d}:     {}".format(i, key))
```

Very convenient indeed.
Do note that keys which contain "." in their name may confuse you a bit in how cascaded they are in the document...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, [Get Field Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-field-mapping.html%3E)

```
def unique_preserving_order(sequence):
    """
    Preserving Order
    :param sequence: object list
    :return:  new list from the set’s contents
    """

    seen = set()
    return [x for x in sequence if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]
```

get es index fields recursively

```
def get_fields_recursively(dct, field_types=None):

    if dct and 'properties' in dct:
        fields = []
        for key, ndct in dct.get('properties').items():
            if 'properties' in ndct:
                for nkey, nd in ndct.items():
                    if nkey == 'properties':
                        field = get_fields_recursively(ndct)

                        if field_types:
                            for f in field:
                                prop = ndct.get('properties').get(f)
                                if prop and prop.get('type') in field_types:
                                    ff = '{0}.{1}'.format(key, f)
                                    # fields.append(f)
                                    fields.append(ff)
                        else:
                            # if not key.startswith('@'):
                            # _fields = field + ['{0}.{1}'.format(key, f) for f in field]
                            _fields = ['{0}.{1}'.format(key, f) for f in field]
                            fields.extend(_fields)
                        continue

                continue

            if field_types:
                if ndct.get('type') in field_types and not key.startswith('@'):
                    fields.append(key)
            else:
                if not key.startswith('@'):
                    fields.append(key)
        return fields
    else:
        return dct
```

get fields from index mappings, also you can filter fields by types, ex. text fields or numerical fields

```
def get_mapping_fields(self, field_type=None, index=None, params={}):
    """

    :param field_type: es field types, filter fields by type
    :param index: elastic index name
    :param params: mapping additional params
    :return: fields

    <https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-field-mapping.html>
    - http://eshost:9200/_mapping
    - http://eshost:9200/_all/_mapping
    - http://eshost:9200/index_name/_mapping

    """

    _fields = []
    _mapping = self.esclient.indices.get_mapping(index=index, params=params)
    for idx_mapping in _mapping.values():
        mapping = idx_mapping.get('mappings')
        if 'system' in mapping:
            mapping = mapping.get('system')
        else:
            mapping = mapping.get('doc')
        fields = get_fields_recursively(mapping, field_type)
        if fields:
            _fields.extend(fields)

    return list(unique_preserving_order(_fields))
```